# Read and Write to database with generic DataTable using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

Is it possible to read and write to a SQL Server database using `DataTable` with Entity Framework?

I have multiple code tables defined in my database such that each of them share a fixed set of properties as shown in the sample below.

For example

```
public class CTGender
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }

    //...Other properties specific to CTGender        
}

public class CTNationality
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }

    //...Other properties specific to CTNationality  
}
```

The situation I face right now is the ever expansion of my code tables, could be another `CTCountry`, `CTRole` and so on, for example.

I am trying to synchronise these code tables between multiple databases.

The solution is heavily dependent on Entity Framework as the data access.

Is there a generic way for Entity Framework to read and write ALL these code tables without their entity models defined, like how you can read and write generic DataTables using ADO.NET?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are couple of ways by which you can create tables at code side then either using code first approach or using publish project mechanism you can generate tables in SQL server using entity framework.
In the latter approach, you can create a separate project where you can write SQL for your various tables. This project should target SQL Server. You can right click on this project and click on publish option for updating all your tables inside SQL server.